# Vim: Go to Beginning/End of Next Method

Tags: java, c++, vim, methods

Is there native functionality in Vim that allows one to move the cursor to the beginning/end of the next method? I already know about `[[`, `]]`, `[]`, and `][`, but these don't cut the job, because they only work on braces that are in column zero. Hence, they are of little use in, say, navigating C++ code. Is there such a command that is already built into Vim? If not, would you recommend a plugin that does implement it?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: `[{` and `}]` will not work all of the time, because you have to be within the block with the `{}` (and not in some deeper scope within that block) for you to end up at the right `{` or `}` afterwards.

Edit 2: Here's a code listing for which `[m` and friends don't work.

```
namespace foo {

#define define_foo         \
    template <class T>     \
    struct foo_traits<X>   \
    {                      \
        using foo = X;     \
    };

template <class T>
struct foo_traits;

define_bar(T*, T*, T*);

template <class T>
struct baz;

template <class T>
struct baz<T&>
{
    static T* apply(T& t) { return &t; }
};

template <class T>
inline T a(T t) { return t; }

}
```

Comment: @EitanT I should have mentioned that those won't work all the time either, because you have to be *inside* the scope of the thing with the `{}`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If that were true, many (dare I say most) people using Vim would no longer be using Vim =)

Comment: What about `]m`, `]M`, `[m` and `]m`?

Comment: @Eitan1 Added a code listing so that we can be explicit about the behavior of the commands.

Comment: @void-pointer I used to use vim only for editing and I wasn't convinced an IDE would make any difference. Eight years ago I switched to using an IDE and when you look at the built-in functionality an IDE gives you today, I can only conclude some people prefer to do things the hard way (admittedly I was one of them)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would be fine with using an IDE if I could still have my Vim navigation and autocommand functionality working. What do you suggest for C++ development on OS X? I agree that C++ and some other languages are sufficiently complex that navigation using Vim's level of intelligence is not very good.

Comment: I am not as familiar with C++, but I have used eclipse. It has a vim plug-in so which is supposed to give you much of the functionality. I find with an IDE much of the need to navigate goes away. e.g. In Java if you use a class, a field or a method which hasn't been imported/defined it will add it in your code without having to scroll to where it goes, add it and scroll back. If you want to move a class between packages, you can drag and drop all the references (even comments, XML and text file references) can be changed. `<Ctrl>+<Click>` jumps to a declaration of something.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There's something called [Eclim](http://eclim.org) that basically runs a headless Eclipse inside Vim; I'll check that out when I get time.

Comment: @EitanT what do exactly these shortcuts do? I just tried them out and it stops sometimes at spacing lines inside a method, other it jumps between methods...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Vim has `[m` / `]m` built in "for Java or similar structured language".

I have written custom versions that handle [Vim functions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4002), [VBScript](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4003), and [batch files](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4004), among others. These are all powered by my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130), which can be used to write custom jump functions based on regular expressions.

Comment: I think support for C++ will require something more powerful than regular expressions, because even `[m`, `]m`, `[M`, `]M` are not working for my C++ code.

Comment: If you're after a 100%-solution, you need a full C++ parser; but usually, a "mostly correct" solution can often be achieved with regexps; cp. Vim's syntax highlighting.

Comment: wow! never knew this motion existed. It works great with typescript/javascript on neovim. I am very happy to discover this built-in vim motion. So cool

Answer (score 13):

I spent hours to make this pattern: **`/^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{`**, it works good for me.

**EDIT**: a better pattern(version 2): **`/\(\(if\|for\|while\|switch\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{`**

**see the effect here:**
[image]
[image]

you can map some convenient **bindings** in your .vimrc, such as:

```
" jump to the previous function
nnoremap <silent> [f :call search('^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{', "bw")<CR>
" jump to the next function
nnoremap <silent> ]f :call search('^\s*\(\i\+\_[ \t\*]\+\)\+\i\+\_s*(\_[^)]*)\_s*{', "w")<CR>
```

**EDIT**: a better pattern(version 2):

```
" jump to the previous function
nnoremap <silent> [f :call
\ search('\(\(if\\|for\\|while\\|switch\\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{', "bw")<CR>
" jump to the next function
nnoremap <silent> ]f :call
\ search('\(\(if\\|for\\|while\\|switch\\|catch\)\_s*\)\@64<!(\_[^)]*)\_[^;{}()]*\zs{', "w")<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks for including full details, including the `noremap` command using `search`.  I had a different issue, but your example cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a duplicate of: [Vim [m motion with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849679/vim-m-motion-with-c-sharp)

You could, for instance, give a try to this dirty trick: `9]}`. 
Which just jumps to the 9-th `}` from the current location (if you're not too nested, should work...)

Answer (score 1):

Vim does not 'understand' your code enough to travel between functions, so the suggested solutions will not work perfectly.

The newer [Helix editor](https://helix-editor.com/) (a modern vim alternative) has tree-sitter integration, which allows you to jump to functions / arguments / methods / classes.

Comment: of course neovim also supports treesitter. https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter

Answer (score 0):

If you use taglist, I added a feature that does just that. You can jump from one tag to the other using Ctrl-up & Ctrl-down, provided the language is supported by taglist.

Here: https://github.com/man9ourah/taglist

and this to your `.vimrc`.

```
nmap <silent> <c-up> <plug>(TlistJumpTagUp)     " Map ctrl-up to move one tag up
nmap <silent> <c-down> <plug>(TlistJumpTagDown) " Map ctrl-down to move one tag down
```