# Move to the previous/next function in AndroidStudio (Vim Emulator)

Tags: android-studio, vim, editor

I'm a vim user and recently I started learning writing apps for Android.
I use Android Studio 2.3.2 with Vim emulator.

As it comes to Vim- I usually use it for C++ programming and one of the features I use on a daily basis is <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to move to the next function and <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to get to the previous function.

When I use that in Android Studio it just moves me to the beginning/end of the file.

My guess is that it is related with opening function scope in the same line instead of in the new line.

**Question:**

Is that possible to jump to next/previous function using Android Studio Vim emulator just as I used to do in C++ code (even though I use Java coding style, a.k.a. "egyptian brackets")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs `:help ]]`

```
                            *]]*
]]          [count] sections forward or to the next '{' in the
            first column.  When used after an operator, then also
            stops below a '}' in the first column.  |exclusive|
            Note that |exclusive-linewise| often applies.
```

Which means it just goes to the next statement that has '{' as the first character of the line, which happens to be the case C and C++ functions (at least in some styleguides), as methods and functions start with a `{`, without any type of nesting.

However, when writing Java, methods are nested inside of classes, which means they usually have a level of indentation.

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128868/835591), Vim has the builtin `[m` and `]m` mappings, to navigate methods.

```
                        *]m*
]m          Go to [count] next start of a method (for Java or
            similar structured language).  When not before the
            start of a method, jump to the start or end of the
            class.  When no '{' is found after the cursor, this is
            an error.  |exclusive| motion.
```

So, if you wish to use `[[` and `]]` for navigating methods, you could remap these in your `~/.ideavimrc`.

```
nnoremap [[ [m
nnoremap ]] ]m
```

Comment: Thats why I love vim. I considered myself an experienced user, but I was not aware of this `]m` and `[m` methods. Works like a charm. Thx